# pthread adds a socket to libevent but exits

Tags: pthreads, libevent

Is it undefined behavior, if a pthread adds a fd to libevent (`event_new` -> `cbk()`) but terminates ? I see that the `cbk()` gets invoked on `EV_READ`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no it is not undefined behavior.

As long as the process where libevent base is created and dispatch function is invoked is running as expected. cbk() should be invoked on EV_READ.